# Need to remove specific HTML tag

Tags: html, tags, filtering

I am trying to support a rich text editor which supports specific tags like `h1`, `h2`, `h3`, `p`, `strong`, `em`, `u`, `sub`, `sup`, `span{!font-family};`, `span{!color};` and `span{!font-size};`.

My requirement is to encode all the other tags which do not fall in the above list so that I can avoid any kind of XSS attacks. Is there a best way to do this on a client side.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [DOMPurify](https://github.com/cure53/DOMPurify). It's a Javascript library for sanitizing HTML that can be configured to serve your needs.

However, I would not recommend using client side escaping when the user's input is going to be sent to your server or stored in a database. You should always sanitize your input on the server-side as well.

Comment: Why would you need sanitizing at both the sides. Are you expecting that someone can catch the request using Fiddler and modify it ?

Comment: Sanitizing at the client side should be done so that: